# What is the difference between "ganz" and "alles"?

Tags: meaning, synonym

Does *ganz* mean the whole of something and *alles* mean all the constituent parts?

> The whole of Germany. => *ganz*
>
> Have we got everything? => *alles*

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/usage-of-die-ganzen

Answer (score 16):

"Ganz" means "the whole". The *entirety* of some *single entity*: "ganz Deutschland": the whole country of Germany.

"Alles" means "all" in the sense that it's about *every element* of some *group*: "alle Deutschen": every single person of German nationality.

Answer (score 1):

Ganz means "whole" and refers to "completeness." "Ganz Deutschland," the "whole" (entire, complete) country of Germany,

Alles means "all" and refers to a "count." "Alle Leute sind hier.": every (single, previously ennumerated) person is here.

Answer (score 1):

In singular: ganz (all, whole, entire, complete): preferred for singular items

> Hast du die ganze Pizza gegessen?
>
> Das ist meine ganze Familie.
>
> Wir haben nicht den ganzen Film gesehen.

In plural:  if there are multiples of something, use “all”:

> Alle Kinder wollen Süßigkeiten.
>
> Kennt ihr alle meine Freunde?

Comment: is here alle as Attribut used or is it a pronoun?