# What is the best way to translate "all the" if not "die ganzen"?

Tags: word-choice

When in English I want to say something like this:

> Where are **all the** log files mentioned in this correspondence?

I write in German:

> Wo sind **die ganzen** Logdateien, die in der Korrespondenz erwähnt sind?

Although it seems that the reader may understand me to mean that I could only find *partial* log files, as if I were saying:

> ...where are **the whole** log files...

What is a better way in German to express the meaning of the expression "*all the*" here?

Comment: +1 because I suppose this is something many non-native speakers have wondered about subconsciously.

Comment: See also: [Usage of “die ganzen …”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/usage-of-die-ganzen)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a very similar construct in German as well:

> Wo sind *all die* Logdateien, die in der Korrespondenz erwähnt sind?

The use of "all" indicates that every single one of the log files is missing, and that this has come as a surprise to the speaker.
If you want to stay a bit more neutral, you could leave "all" out and simply ask

> Wo sind die Logdateien, die in der Korrespondenz erwähnt sind?

Finally, "die ganzen" should also be understood, especially if emphasized correctly (emphasis in bold):

> Wo sind die ganzen **Logdateien**, die in der Korrespondenz erwähnt sind? >>> ...all the...
>
> Wo sind die **ganzen** Logdateien, die in der Korrespondenz erwähnt sind? >>> ...the whole...

Comment: Widely used is *"wo sind **denn** all die..."*.

Comment: +1, though I think that "all die" does only indicate that a lot more files were expected, not that *every single one* is missing. If you expected hundreds of files and there were only a few, "all die" would still be fine.

Comment: I would prefer "Wo zur Hölle sind denn die verf*ckten Logdateien?", but +1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about people understanding "die ganzen" as "the whole ones" - in fact this meaning would be highly unidiomatic. You'd probably say "die vollständigen" if you want to express this.

"Die ganzen ..." *is* the best way to translate what you want to say here. :)

[Jan's suggestion "*all die* Logdateien" is definitely correct and idiomatic - but when I try to picture someone saying this I see either someone trying to be funny (probably making a sad, bewildered face) or `<disablepoliticalcorrectness>` the stereotypical blonde `</disablepoliticalcorrectness>` - no offence meant, I just can't think of a more concise way to express what I want to say...
In a nutshell: "all die" is definitely marked usage]